Laravel 11 Connect Microsoft Azure SQL Server on Mac OS Sonoma M1
I am trying to connect Laravel 11 to Microsoft Azure SQL Server on Mac OS Sonoma M1
Before I try to install Microsoft Azure SQL Server Edge (as Microsoft SQL Server alternative for Mac OS with M1 Chip) on Docker, I follow tutorial from https://dev.to/avwerosuoghene/installing-ms-sql-server-on-mac-m1-chip-30d0 step by step until success and now its works fine.
also after I test connection using terminal with command
mssql -u SA -p MyPassword

its connected and works fine.

then I try to download Azure Data Studio as GUI Interface for the SQL Server Database, then I try to connect via that GUI, again its connected successfully and works fine.


by the way the computer name is afb6f21ec9ac as you can see on the above picture, and also if I run the command on terminal: docker ps

I have install the Microsoft Driver for PHP 8.2.0 for SQL Server on Mac (SQLSRV & PDO_SQLSRV) using this tutorial: https://github.com/Braineee/microsoft-driver-on-mamp-for-mac/blob/master/README.md, until successfully done and its works fine.
we can see using phpinfo() if SQLSRV & PDO_SQLSRV are installed successfully


then I try to connect the SQL Server (Azure Edge) with the Laravel 11
and here is my DB Connection Configuration on .env
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=MyDatabase
DB_USERNAME=SA
DB_PASSWORD=MyPassword

but when I try to show the DB or migrate the database using php artisan command to test the connection between Laravel 11 and SQL Server (Azure) on Docker, its ERROR !! and give me Some ERROR MESSAGE !!


FYI, I am using:

PHP 8.2.0
Mamp Pro 6.8
Microsoft Azure SQL Server EDGE (Database)
Microsoft Azure Data Studio 1.48.0 (GUI)
Mac OS Sonoma 14.5 with M1 Chip
Docker 4.30.0
Laravel 11.0.8
Docker Container ID: afb6f21ec9ac
server localhost/127.0.0.1 port 1433
DB Name: MyDatabase
DB Username: SA
DB Password: MyPassword
Project Laravel Folder: MyLaravel

please help me, why I can connect the database via terminal and via Database GUI but cannot connect via laravel altough I have install Microsoft Driver For PHP 8.2.0 and SQL Server (SQLSRV & PDO_SQLSRV) ??
thanks for your help :)

sqlsrv doesn't directly connect to SQL Server itself, it connects via ODBC drivers. Did you skip the brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools step that installs ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server?

@AlwaysLearning I have install microsoft/mssql-release/mssql-tools and when I try to run brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools, there is message that microsoft/mssql-release/mssql-tools 17.10.1.1 is already installed and up-to-date.

I found the answer here: Laravel 10 stopped working with SQL Server Database
on thats answer, @bjauy give two options that I can choose:

downgrade the php version
or temporarily comment out PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES in sqlsrv section of config/database.php and in $options of vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SqlServerConnector.php

and I choose the last one, so I comment out the PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES on  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SqlServerConnector.php
and also I change the SESSION_DRIVER=database to SESSION_DRIVER=file on .env
Now its works fine, I can select, insert, update and delete data via Laravel 11 on my table using Microsoft Azure SQL Server Edge installed local on MacOS Sonoma with M1 Chip
